# How to identify Processor Architecture in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, .net, xamarin

Lets say mostly all android processors are of type ARM but for testing, emulators are mostly of type x86. I native library that only runs on ARM and I just want to put dummy code for x86 in order to create Unit tests. I know simple try/catch will suffice, but problem is I wan to create interface with dummy code for unit tests.

I have tried,

```
        System.Reflection.PortableExecutableKinds peKind;
        System.Reflection.ImageFileMachine machine;
        typeof(object).Module.GetPEKind(out peKind, out machine);
```

And various answers I found for .net, but while in Android, I get x86 always, though I am running app on device, it does not give me correct answer.

```
  type(object).Assembly.GetName().ProcessorArchitecture
```

Always returns x86.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Android.OS.Build Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.Build/) to help you confirm if the device is ARM or Intel x86 ([Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/16/how-to-identify-the-image-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-user-space)) `armeabi-v7a` or `x86` etc.

```
IList<string> abis = Android.OS.Build.SupportedAbis;
```

**Alternatively**

You can use [Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty/p/System.String/) to get the OS architecture, `armv71` and `i686` etc.

```
string osArchitecture = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.GetProperty("os.arch");
```