# Secure localisation app Xamarin.Forms , Xamarin.Ios , Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Good morning ,
I am developing a xamarin application which allows you to locate its user.

Given the importance of the user's location, I must reassure myself of the use of the exact location, i.e. avoid that:

- Do not mislead the application with a fake GPS application (justify Location of xamarin essentials which allows you to manage this)
- That the user cannot install the software on the PC emulators.
- That the user cannot inject code to avoid this verification.

Are there any solutions in xamarin allowing me to resolve these problems in a secure and efficient manner in order to achieve my objectives (have a reliable location).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Xamarin.Essentials: Geolocation`. It has the method to detecte Mock Locations.

```
var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

if (location != null)
{
    if(location.IsFromMockProvider)
    {
        // location is from a mock provider
    }
}
```

> That the user cannot install the software on the PC emulators.

First, you can add permission to read the file system in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Second, Create a method to read the contents of '/proc/cpuinfo':

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public string GetCpuInfo()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("/proc/cpuinfo"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then, you can call this method get and display CPU information.

```
string cpuInfo = GetCpuInfo();
```

Comment: Yes, I have already used this method and it detects fake geolocation applications but my problem is that we can bypass the location by using an emulator like BlueStacks (you can change the location and the app does not detect it)

How to distinguish a device from an emulator with Xamarin.Form.

Comment: You can use the [Xamarin.Essentials: Device Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?tabs=ios) to distinguish between physical device and emulator.

Comment: Yes I used that but it always comes back physical

Comment: I tested on my side by using the Xamarin.Essentials version 1.8.0 and it comes back with virtual on the Android Emulator. You can check the version and update it to the latest.

Comment: I'm talking about emulators like BlueStacks, they allow you to install the apks on a PC and use the application.

Comment: Yes, I know. BlueStacks can even change the device model and code to masquerade as the physical device. This might be difficult to recognize it.

Comment: Ah ok so there is no solution to prevent this circumvention?

Comment: It might be worthwhile looking at some sensors or the CPU model of the device which wouldn't be present in a physical device to recognize if it is an emulator.

Comment: Ok these are possible solutions.

Do you have any links to get this information from the phone?

Comment: You can check this link about [How to identify Processor Architecture in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112544/how-to-identify-processor-architecture-in-xamarin-android#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20Android.OS.Build%20Class%20to%20help%20you,get%20the%20OS%20architecture%2C%20armv71%20and%20i686%20etc.).

Comment: Yes when I run these codes on emulators and some real phones the only difference is that in the emulator I always have the x86_64 ABI in addition.

But by searching in depth I see that there are phones which also have this ABI (x86_64) as described in this link

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis?hl=en#java

So by relying on it we are going on the wrong track

Comment: That might be the wrong direction, but we know that the emulator I always have the x86_64 ABI, that is a great information. You can try to get the CPU model of the device and check the ABI together to distinguish the emulator.

Comment: I write a demo for you to get the cpu model you can check the answer I updated.

Comment: Okay I'm waiting for your demo thank you in advance

Comment: Ok I executed your code but I see that it is practically the same values which come out on the device and on the simulator just that the BlueStacks simulator returns a Serial part: 0000000000001.

I have another Google Integrety API https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview?hl=en solution that may solve the problem.